# Category menu of Netbeans do not load?

Tags: 12.04, netbeans

[image]When I was going to start a new project, a dialog box came, but the categories did not load.How to fix this issue?
I am using Ubuntu 12.04 64-bits
Netbeans 7.0.1

Comment: Do you mean that the dialog window was empty? Could you add a screenshoot?

Comment: ok see the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear the personnel config in ~/.netbeans/ if it's not a fresh install. This may come from plugins too...